# Removing all after specific character in Django

Tags: django

**This is my string:**

```
Text1 - Text2 - Text2
```

**This is the output wanted:**

```
Text1
```

I looked for a filter that could do this, but couldn't find it. I'll need something like this:

```
{{ product.title | split(' - ')[0] }}
```

Thanks.

Comment: We need more details. Are you trying to pass the string into your template and then change it? Or are you wanting to split the string before you pass it through your context?

Comment: I need something like this {{ product.title | split(' - ')[0] }}

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your view.

```
product_text = product.title
split_text = product_text.split("-")[0]
```

Then pass this `split_text` through your context and reference it in your template. `{{split_text}}`